# Getting error: "org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Jpeg contains more than one Photoshop App13 segment" when parsing image

Tags: java, image, apache, image-processing

I'm using [Apache-commons-imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html) to parse images in order to get the width, height and color model. I use the `Imaging.getImageInfo` method to get the image information. However, on certain JPEG files the library is throwing the following error:

```
 org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Jpeg contains more than one Photoshop App13 segment
```

The JPEG image seem to be valid and I don't think it should be getting rejected. I haven't been able to find any useful information on how to fix this issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this or does anyone have an alternative library to parse images in low latency?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach or link the JPEG file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMAGING-100) has been already created many years ago and still nothing. It seems that there's no support for JPEGs with multiple App13 segments at the moment.